# merging two lists of dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, join

I  have two datasets that look at follows (the two datasets are much longer 10k-18k.)
Let me know if I need to add more entries to the example.

```
A = [{'air_temperature_celcius': '7', 'date' : 2010-08-20', 'relative_humidity' : '37.9', 'station': '2002-022A', 'wind_speed_knots': '5.5'}] 

B = [{'latitude': '-37.591', 'longitude': '148.111', 'datetime':'2019-10-02T03:52:12', 'surface_temp':'57', 'confidence': '83', 'power' : '26.7'}]
```

Given that they don't have a similar key, how what would i go about joining them? The closest is probably key: `date` and key: `datetime` but they are different values. I plan on using a divide and broadcast based parallel join algorithm, possibly with hash-based local joining? I'm just not sure how to join them when they have no common attribute.

thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: can you show your attempt

Comment: In your example, the dictionaries are almost a decade apart.  Should the result merge dictionaries from A & B which are the same to a day (i.e. least granular time reference of A & B)?

Comment: I'm not wanting code, i can right that myself. what i need help with is what to join the two tables on as from what i know they need to have a shared key right? Also the dates range from 2009 to 2019 in both datasets

Comment: @BethanyHooper--finding a common key was the reason for my question. The only common field is date, but in your example, they are far apart.  The question is how close do they need to be to consider the dates to match from A & B (i.e. is to a day a match for instance)?

Comment: I would say to the day, but there are multiple entries for each day in data set B as it also takes time into account in the 'datetime' attribute. So would I need to subset the attribute to just display the date?

Comment: @BethanyHooper--"So would I need to subset the attribute to just display the date?"  Not sure if I understand this question.  The idea is that keys can be derived based upon the date strings you have in A & B.  However, if you have multiple entries on the same day for B, but say only one in A, what would you want the result to be?

Comment: That the issue, I just need to join A & B together but I'm not told what the result should be or look like. The question is literally "Please use the divide and broadcast based parallel join algorithm and any local join technique to join datasets A and B and find surface temperature, air temperature, relative humidity and wind speed".

Answer (score 0):

Since A and B are lists you can use the extend() method to merge them as `A.extend(B)`.

Comment: I am looking to do a particular parallel join method... unfortunately A.extend(B) will not cut it